# trying to get PDO to load

Tags: php, php-7.2

I'm trying to get PDO to load on a PHP7.2 apache server (aws)

I keep running into these errors

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/pdo.so' - /usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line
```

additionally php is throwing this error:

```
PHP Warning: ob_start(): function 'mb_output_handler' not found or invalid function name in /var/app/ondeck/laravel/core.php on line 32
```

I am unsure why the server is throwing those errors, I have in the php config

```
   extension=pdo.so
      extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

I expect that it would load pdo into php 7 unless these commands/extensions are outdated and php7 requires something new?

UPDATE: the rest of the config file that I can share, please be aware I didn't write the original code:

```
     yum -y install \
  php72-fpm

  # Make sure php is on for server reboot
  chkconfig php-fpm on

  # Add some extra settings for php
  cat > /etc/php-fpm.d/extra.conf <<EOF
  [www]
  request_terminate_timeout=600s

  ; Connections
  pm.max_children = 60
  pm.start_servers = 30
  pm.min_spare_servers = 30
  pm.max_spare_servers = 30
  pm.max_requests = 100
  EOF

  # replace the web user in the php-fpm conf file
  sed -i.bak 's/user = apache/user = webapp/g' /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

  # Add this to /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpfpm.conf
  # Pass requests into php-fpm
  cat > /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpfpm.conf <<EOF
  <IfModule proxy_module>
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/public_html/$1 timeout=600
  </IfModule>
  EOF

  # Remove contents of the 10-php.conf file (loads php_mod for apache)
  cat > /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-php.conf <<EOF
  EOF

  # Remove the 2 lines of php variables that use the php5_mod
  sed -i.bak 's/php_value session.save_handler "files"//g' /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf
  sed -i.bak 's/php_value session.save_path    "\/var\/lib\/php\/session"//g' /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf

  # restart php
  service php-fpm restart

  service httpd graceful
```

Comment: Can you share more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to load modules by PHP 5.5 from path /usr/lib64/php/5.5/, but you run PHP 7.x. That does not work, so you need to install the correct modules.

Comment: Thanks - I've switched to php72-fpm and the server now works but it stops fpm because it can't communicate with apache?

Comment: Well, that's another roblem and therefore has nothing to do with your question here.

Comment: I corrected the module I just can't apache to read the php file now (different problem). I tried getting your email through your website to have a conversation about it but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I believe you haven't installed the required PHP modules:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: it's amazon linux so I think I have to use yum and the packages are different...? (I tried those and it didn't work).

Comment: Did you verify the loaded configuration file? echo phpinfo & check the Loaded Configuration File.

Comment: no, the only thing that loads is the front end and I don't even know if the php runs - for now it isn't erroring. I'm thinking the communication between apache and fpm has stopped